# What is wrong with this Java code from tutorial?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, spring, hibernate

I got troubled in my first day in **Hibernate**+ **Java EE**+ **Spring** + **Eclipse**. Well I was getting through J2EE, Spring & Eclipse for the last few days, now I am getting my first DB connected application.

Hope to break things soon and start with a xerox copy(Make it Simple policy).
I don't meant to do any harm to the original code in this [tutorial](http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/hibernate/hibernate_web_example.html).

The only change is in DB username and password:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
...
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jwt</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
...
```

Getting things transferred to the **"Details Added"** page and with this error in the console:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment). log4j:WARN Please initialize the
>   log4j system properly.
>
> Could not parse mapping document from resource
>   com/jwt/hibernate/bean/user.hbm.xml error

So I am running late on this. Please, let me know if the error is in the code or accessing a DB table in tomcat server which is created in WAMP server?

Don't feel like I am solving this simple issue by this simple question. Actually I have tried the issue everywhere and still no solution helps.

- Note that I'm running **Tomcat7** for this and created the table from **WAMP**.

**UPDATE:**

here is the **user.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.jwt.hibernate.bean.User" table="USER">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" />
        <property column="USER_NAME" name="userName" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="PASSWORD" name="password1" type="string" />
        <property column="EMAIL" name="email" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="PHONE" name="phone" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property column="CITY" name="city" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Fields are the same `ID`(int), `USER_NAME`(varchar),`PASSWORD`(varchar), `EMAIL`(varchar), `PHONE`(varchar), `CITY`(varchar) in DB table `USER`.

Comment: You did read the error message that said the problem is with the file `user.hbm.xml`, right?

Comment: I think It's missing the log4j jar file in classpath. please recheck whether you have added it properly

Comment: Here is your error on your user.hbm.xml `<property column="PASSWORD" name="password1" type="string" />` it should be `type="java.lang.String"`

Comment: @DesirePRG : I have WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-1.2.11.jar file available in the workspace.

Comment: @JorgeCampos :No changes

Comment: Any stacktrace besides the error you show?

Comment: Have you tried adding a generator to your id in your mapping file?

Comment: @sanwrit : Sorry, I don't get it. I am just in. Let me know about adding a generator to ID if you dont mind.

Comment: If your tutorial teaches you that Hibernate mapping is done using xml files, it's outdated. Read a tutorial that teaches you to map entities using JPA annotations. XML was necessary when we were on Java 4. But we're now at Java 8.

Comment: If you really need this to work, refer to the following: [hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) and [tutorial using xml and annotation](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-3-with-maven-2-and-mysql-5-example-xml-mapping-and-annotation/)